# Users can only see folder in shared Documents folder

Tags: sharepoint-online

I created a '**Document Center**' SharePoint site, put some files and a folder with some files in it, then I went to **Site Contents -> Site Settings -> People and Groups**. From there I added members of our secretaries Teams team to the '**Members**' group. The group permission is '**contribute**'. When the secretaries go to look at the   files from their Teams team or in SharePoint, they only see the folder I created but no files. I can see everything. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the files you uploaded are not still checked out to you.  In the modern list view there will be a tiny red arrow next to the file name of files you currently have checked out.

Comment: Thank you! That was certainly happening.